# laravel is there a way to get smallest or highest id

Tags: database, laravel

Is there a way to get the smallest and highest id in your table and check that in an if / else statement?

I already tried `$user->first()` and `$user->last()` but those did not work well.

Comment: Hi Gijs, perhaps it'll help us more (to help you) if you can provide a bit more of your code. E.g. what sort of if/else statement, and elaborate more on 'did not work well' (what were you expect? what did show up?)

Answer (score 3):

Use the min/max functions of Eloquent.

```
User::max('id');
User::min('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the highest and User id's

`User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->id;`

`User::orderBy('id', 'asc')->first()->id;`

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "check that in an if / else statement." If you could provide a little more explanation I'd be able to help more.